# Replacing the td data with the input box changes the with of column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

Well the problem I hope is simple, table represents data and by hovering the td element I replace it with text input. The problem is that the input box has some default width and this makes the table flicker.

How to set the input box correctly with? Should I take the first td width size and simply set to the input box?

http://jsfiddle.net/staar2/Pufpq/2/

// A bit more better, fonts were different in input box and outside

http://jsfiddle.net/Pufpq/7/

// Remove outline
http://jsfiddle.net/Pufpq/8/

I think the problem is now found, when setting the text a bit bigger then the width the row scales bigger but the input box fits the text inside and does not change width.

Comment: Just set the width? I am confused

Comment: The code is posted in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/staar2/Pufpq/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a width to the td and the input inside the td make the flicker less obvious.

```
td {
padding: 5px; 
width:10px;    
}

td input {
    width:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

style the input with a specific width (not 100%, but like 100px) and that should fix it

Comment: As i can see the other three post has the same answer by specifying certain width to table and then to each input same width. Well it's much better than before but the problem remains same. I also suggest adding some wrapper with padding ?

Comment: I don't see why you need an input anyway. They are used with forms and you don't have a form there, so if you're not going to do posting, why not just add a `<div>` instead, which doesn't have any implicit measurements?

Comment: Well here's the picture http://10rem.net/media/38663/WindowsLiveWriter_CustomizingtheCaretandSelectionStylesinW_D35_image_8.png

Answer (score 0):

You could get the table cell width before you make the change and then apply it afterward, but you would also need to compensate for any padding, margins, and border.